# Prevent libavformat (FFmpeg) from adding "ENCODER" tag to output / help stripping the tags

Tags: audio, encoding, ffmpeg, tags, metadata

I made a bash script that transfers audio or video metadata from one file to another, regardless of media container format, via FFMpeg. My problem is that FFMpeg consistently adds a 'ENCODER' tag.

Example:

Before running through FFMpeg:

File: track01.cdda.flac

```
  Metadata:
    ALBUM           : Wish You Were Here
    ARTIST          : Pink Floyd
    COPYRIGHT       : 1975 Harvest Records
    DATE            : 1975
    GENRE           : Experimental Rock
    TITLE           : Shine On You Crazy Diamond
    track           : 1
```

After running through FFMpeg:

File: track01-iphone-alac.m4a

```
  Metadata:
    ALBUM=Wish You Were Here
    ARTIST=Pink Floyd
    COPYRIGHT=1975 Harvest Records
    DATE=1975
    GENRE=Experimental Rock
    TITLE=Shine On You Crazy Diamond
    track=1
    ENCODER=Lavf55.12.100
```

So really, I want to either force FFMpeg to **not** add the 'ENCODER' tag, or I want to strip that tag off afterwards. Is there a way to do this? I really don't want to spend hours trying to compile FFMpeg again on my Pentium 4 HT - the only working computer I have at the moment. I'd prefer not to have to use another program unless it's related enough to FFMpeg or MPlayer/Mencoder that I won't have to install anything new if I have those installed.

Comment: Why do you want to remove/prevent it?

Comment: Because I hate when a program adds anything I don't explicitly tell it to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't `-metadata encoder='my encoder'` command-line option work?

Comment: aha! the ffmpeg manpage is huge :p I didn't quite figure that out.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, at least not for Ogg Vorbis files.

Answer (score 9):

Old question but in case someone needs it, I found this works to prevent the creation of the Encoder tag, at least on MP4 files.

```
-fflags +bitexact
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the following bug report:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6602

It seems this is intentional and has been reported as a bug, correctly IMHO.